# FileUpload to load .XML

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I was previously loading an XML file by using:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("File.xml");
        Visit(doc.Root);
```

Now I want to load the file by using a FileUpload box:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(FileUpload1.FileContent);
        Visit(doc.root);
```

But now I'm getting an error on "(doc.root)" . It says that "does not contain a definition for 'Root' and no extension method 'Root' accepting a first argument type". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Root` and `root` are capitalised differently in your two examples. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because XmlDocument doesnt have a root property; The root of the XmlDocument is represented by the DocumentElement property of the object, in your case: `doc.DocumentElement` and since your method receives an XElement parameter as input you will need to convert the XmlElement to an XElement before passing it into your Visit() method. Use the function below for doing it.

```
  /// <summary>  
  /// Converts an XmlElement to an XElement.  
  /// </summary>  
  /// <param name="xmlelement">The XmlElement to convert.</param>  
  /// <returns>The equivalent XElement.</returns>  
  public static XElement ToXElement(XmlElement xmlelement)  
  {    
     return XElement.Load(xmlelement.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree());  
  }
```

Then try calling in this way:

```
  Visit(ToXElement(doc.DocumentElement));
```

Comment: Like this? Visit(doc.DocumentElement);

It says that it has some invalid arguments...

Comment: Yes, there's not root property into XmlDocument but the DocumentElement will represent the actual root of your XML.

Comment: What is the signature of your Visit method, what's the type of the object it receives??

Comment: public static void Visit(XElement element)

Comment: you will need to conver the XmlElement from the XmlDocument to an XElement before passing it. I'll update the answer with the code to convert it. Give me a few minutes

Comment: @Mark-AR I've updated the answer, please review it and let me know if you need any more help.